# Proxy authentication troubleshooting

Tags: authentication, browser, proxy, dump

When using proxy authentication is there a way to do a browser dump to see what actually gets sent to site trying to access?

Lands on site without breaking out of proxy but not actually authenticating properly. Proxy IPs not being sent properly it seems. Would like to see what does get sent.

Thanks!